# Obtain all current Amazon RDS Engine Versions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to obtain a list of all available Engine Versions for each AWS RDS Engine.

```
    Amazon.RDS.AmazonRDSClient rdsClient;
    List<DBEngineVersion> versions = new List<DBEngineVersion>();
    versions = rdsClient.DescribeDBEngineVersions().DBEngineVersions;
```

However I cannot obtain a complete list of all engine versions. For some engine types such as MySQL or Oracle I can obtain all the versions, but for most of the engine types, I cannot obtain any of the versions.

How do I get all of the engine versions for all engines?

Answer (score 6):

Use below cli command to get list of all RDS Engine versions.

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --region ap-southeast-2 --output json --profile temp --query 'DBEngineVersions[*].{Engine:Engine,EngineVersion:EngineVersion}'
```

Comment: I need a solution that utilizes the .NET library. Unless I can invoke that method from within a .NET app somehow?